# By using Replace/Regex, replace text with ignore list of words

Tags: python, regex, replace

For example, I have the text:

```
x = "xyz SAMPLE Text XX 12345"
```

and now I will use simple replace function

```
x.replace("XX","UniqueValue")
```

Is there a way to add an ignore list to this functionality, e.g. if "Text XX" is in the ignore list, then the function will see, AH I need to replace `XX` with `UniqueValue`, but in the ignore list there is `Text XX` so I should not touch it.

PC.. Ignore list should be as an array.

Is it possible and what is the potential approach to do it?

Comment: using regex `"(Text XX)|XX"` and replace with captured group 1 or `"UniqueValue"`, the principle is to match the unwanted pattern first in alternative otherwise the wanted. Due to backtracking.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul I need to ignore from replace not to replace to something else to ignore it , as it should be reused for other replace methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple solution. It may need enhance if you provide more test cases.

```
import hashlib

x1 = "xyz SAMPLE Text XX 12345"
x2 = "Text XX and XX"


def replace_with_ignore(s, replace_dict, ignore_lst=[]):
    ignore_hash_d = {i: hashlib.sha1(i.encode()).hexdigest() for i in ignore_lst}
    for k, v in replace_dict.items():
        r = replace_dict[k]
        ignore_contains_set = set([i for i in ignore_lst if k in i])
        ignore_contains_list = sorted(list(ignore_contains_set),
                                      key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True)
        for ic in ignore_contains_list:
            s = s.replace(ic, ignore_hash_d[ic])
        s = s.replace(k, r)
        for ic in ignore_contains_list:
            s = s.replace(ignore_hash_d[ic], ic)
    return s


print(replace_with_ignore(x1, {'XX': 'YY'}))
# xyz SAMPLE Text YY 12345
print(replace_with_ignore(x1, {'XX': 'YY'}, ['Text XX']))
# xyz SAMPLE Text XX 12345
print(replace_with_ignore(x2, {'XX': 'YY'}))
# Text YY and YY
print(replace_with_ignore(x2, {'XX': 'YY'}, ['Text XX']))
# Text XX and YY
```

Comment: Would this work for a case "Text XX and XX"?

Comment: @Kris i solved your test case, by replace larger ignore with hash first, then convert back. i know there should be other failing cases, but i hope will be enough for OP.

Comment: This is just awesome! To be honest I have not thought that it could be that clean as a OP, Thank you!

Comment: nice to know it helped :) i just updated to be more robust.

Comment: But I seriously think investing a little time on look-ahead and look-behind regexes with a negation will be much faster. @LeiYang No offense to this wonderful piece of work

Comment: thanks. i'd like to see some regex answers too. my solution still has some easy to fail cases, such as what if replaced value concat words beside, and combination contains another replace key?

Answer (score 0):

I have a not so clever solution, turn all old values to new values first, then if the new values is preceded by ignored items, turn them back to old values.

```
def partial_replace(s, old, new, ignored):
    s = s.replace(old, new)
    for i in ignored:
        s = s.replace(f"{i} {new}", f"{i} {old}")
    return s

s = "xyz XX SAMPLE XX Text XX 12345 XX"
print(partial_replace(s, "XX", "UniqueValue", ["xyz", "Text"]))
```

Output:

```
xyz XX SAMPLE UniqueValue Text XX 12345 UniqueValue
```